# Create a new frame/window in Javascript canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

How can I create a new frame/window in the canvas?  I am trying to make a game, and have a feature when you press a button, a menu screen will pop up displaying a bunch of information.  Currently I have it working where you press a button and it will pop up with a placeholder image, which I would now like to replace.

I know in Java you would just create a new JFrame or JPanel, but how do you do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's modal dialog is popular:

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

The jquery modal dialog window is an overlaying div element positioned within the viewport and is protected from page content (like select elements) shining through with an iframe. It has a title bar and a content area, and can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon by default.

**Define your popup window**

You define the jquery dialog window by creating a div element containing your informational contents.

```
<div id="MyInfo" title="My Popup dialog">

  <p id="myContent">Here is 'a bunch of information' and images too!<p>

  <img src="anyImage.png">

</div>
```

**Display your popup window**

jQuery will initially hide your popup div.  You can display the popup div like this;

```
$( "#MyInfo" ).dialog("open");
```

So if you want the popup to display when you press a button you can do this:

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){  $("#MyInfo").dialog("open"); });
```

And, Yes, you can get your desired contents through AJAX calls and then put that info into your the jquery popup.

```
$("#myContent").text("Here's some info from an AJAX GET request");
```

There are quite a few useful options that can be used with the jQuery dialog including animations and buttons.

Comment: Would Ajax be used with this?